# Получить массив статей RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Я в `php` получаю статьи таким образом, что я получаю массив из всех статьей

```php
$articles_q = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM `articles`');
$articles = [];
while ($art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles_q)) {
    $articles[] = $art;
}
```

Я бы хотел это сделать с помощью `RedBeanPHP`, подскажите, какая функция может мне это сделать?

Comment: Руководства читать нонче не принято?

Comment: [Querying RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я придумал такой способ

```php
$articles_r = R::findCollection('articles', '');
$articles = [];
while($art = $articles_r -> next()) {
    $articles[] = $art;
}
```